# Have most countries used plutonium/implosion approach in developing their atomic weapons?

Tags: atomic-weapons

I am aware that the USA first dropped the gun-type but first ***tested*** (unsure of approach) the implosion design in 1945 -- the gun-type was never tested before use because its design was so simple. Bethe pointed out that the plutonium weapon requires machining of the metal, and there is also afaik a still-classified initiator which is pretty complex itself.

Would even in the 21st century a country like North Korea use the simpler design to be sure of success or are there other reasons that they would use the implosion design despite its relative complexity?

Comment: Any approach will require machining or otherwise forming the appropriate shapes - you don’t find them lying around in nature. One path to take is to look at the gun-type weapons through history and why the gun-type was chosen.

Comment: I’ll note that B. Cameron Reed has a number of freely accessible papers on the physics and history of the Manhattan Project. They may prove useful.

Comment: Is this a history question?

Comment: @kimchilover - I would say that which countries pursued what approaches is a history question.

Comment: @JonCuster: Bethe mentioned machining plutonium -- if uranium also requires machining, plutonium might be harder to machine or since it is used in implosions, it has to be more precisely machined. Obviously, machining of plutonium is very, very dangerous, i think the dust is much worse than uranium dust (although both are toxic/radioactive). Bethe was talking about why a terrorist organization would not be able to make an implosion weapon.

Comment: Yes, generally an implosion type requires more finesse. Note one can use uranium in implosion devices as well as plutonium. If they could machine it in the 40’s well enough, any reasonably funded group can do it now, particularly if they are not concerned about worker safety…

Comment: @JonCuster: Bethe in the 1980s or later thought machining plutonium was a challenge; Bethe probably knew what he was talking about although perhaps sacrificing safety gets beyond most problems.

Comment: Both Pu and U are pyrophoric, making it a bit of a challenge, sure.

Comment: @JonCuster: I was surprised that U is also pyrophoric and just off the top of my non-chemist  head, I think its radioactivity is why. My sense from what I recall from Bethe is that Pu is a special problem to machine. You know perhaps also that the initiator for an implosion device is a very complex thing which implies that gun-types are what many countries try to make.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_Africa_and_weapons_of_mass_destruction), South Africa developed and made operational a handful of uranium gun devices. No plutonium devices were made.

So, at least one country went for the simple design.

Libya ([also on Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libya_and_weapons_of_mass_destruction) is another possibility, but apparently their program never progressed very well. They intended to enrich uranium, but whether that was to go directly to a gun-type weapon or as a stepping stone to breeding plutonium is unclear.